# How to solve Error: ENOENT, stat

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, stylus

I´ve installed NPM and stylus global way in Mac OS,  but when I try create a new-file.styl the following error occurs:

```
$ stylus -c -w mi-estilo.styl
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:640
    if (err) throw err;
               ^
Error: ENOENT, stat 'mi-estilo.styl'
    at Error (native)
```

I searched the solution, but . . . I don't have any success.

could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that it expects to find 'mi-estilo.styl'. You seem to expect that it should be created. Looking at `stylus --help`, `-c` option is for "compress" and `-w` is for "watch", there is no indication that something should be created.